# USB as a host Data Transfer problems for SCSI READ command

Tags: embedded, usb, scsi

I am implementing USB as a host using OHCI. And using SCSI to read a mass storage device.
All my control transfers run successfully. I have done all the initialization using Control Transfers however I am facing problem with Data Transfers.

I am having troubles in successfully implementing the READ command in SCSI, be it READ(6), READ(10), etc.

The following is a snapshot of the Command Block Wrapper(CBW)-
[image]

The highlighted portion is the SCSI command.

As You can see I have requested 512 bytes- which is the size of 1 LBA for my mass storage device.

The following is what comes in the 512 byte buffer from the device-
[image]

FYI- The buffer was initialized to 0xff
These 512 bytes are not present anywhere on my mass storage device. I opened the mass storage device on HXD and checked the bytes to see that the block I received doesnt exist on my mass storage!

And the Command Status Wrapper (CSW) I got was as follows-
[image]

Last byte in CSW is 0x01 which means the command failed.
I have 3 questions
1- What could be the reason why this READ is failing? Am I supposed to run any other SCSI command before this for any reason?
2- I request for 512 bytes and I even get that but the bytes 8-11 in CSW which show residue still show a certain value a which happens to be greater than 512 (as this is little endian format). How is this possible? 
3- What could the 512 bytes I receive from the device possibly be?

Any helps with this I have been stuck here for a looong time now and I dont have a USB analyzer.

Pseudo code for Data Transfers-
Set the Endpoint Descriptor (ED) 1 (Indication the OUT Endpoint)
Set the Transfer Descriptor (TD) 1 (Send SCSI command)

Set the BulkHead  ED to ED 1
Start the descriptor processing
and then
stop it

Set the Endpoint Descriptor (ED) 1 (Indication the IN Endpoint)
Set the Transfer Descriptor (TD) 1 (Read the 512 bytes)
Set the Transfer Descriptor (TD) 2 (Read the 13 CSW bytes)

Set the BulkHead  ED to ED 1
Start the descriptor processing
and then
stop it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These 512 bytes are not present anywhere on my mass storage device.

No, this looks very much like a valid sector `0` to me.

What you probalbly miss ist that Windows does not allow a non-admin user to look at this sector at all. HXD thus shows you the first sector of the *partition*, which is *not* sector `0`. You would see this only with admin priviliges and when opening the corresponding physical disk.

> I request for 512 bytes and I even get that but the bytes 8-11 in CSW which show residue still show a certain value a which happens to be greater than 512

No, you request `256*512` bytes. The byte order for those SCSI length fields is AFAIK big endian.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I understood the second solution you gave and have fixed that. Now my read command RUNS successfully! However I did not understand the first part. When I open up my flash drive on HXD I see the following- imgur.com/wrUY5PQ How do I access this? Because only on parsing this will I get info on the USB

Comment: Also I hope u can help me through with this one because I really dont find help from anyone on this topic

Comment: HxD has physical devices under its own tree, those are without a drive letter. You need to run it as admin to be able to open a physical device.

Comment: ....I got it all figured out!! Thanks a ton!! The response that I got was for sector 0 which is the MBR. I saw how to parse the MBR to get information about the partitions!
Thanks for your help!